# Como extrair strings de 4 arquivos diferente, e inserir numa única linha de um documento HTML

Tags: linux, loop, for, bash, while

Há horas tô tentando uma maneira de fazer a inclusão do conteúdo de 4 arquivos distintos para um novo arquivo de saída -; "saida.html". Os 4 arquivos que estou buscando extrair informações são:

- link.txt
- foto.txt
- legenda.txt
- nome.txt

**Importante!** - ja que os arquivos e seus respectivos conteúdos estão sobre minha costódia, ou seja, na minha máquina. E não seria viável postar tudo por aqui.

> Peço a quem puder dar aquela força tarefa, que crie os arquivos em seu PC: com o comando `touch` ou `echo`
>
> Adicione links fictícios ao arquivo link.txt. Exemplo:
>
> - www.seusite.comigo
> - www.seusite.no.ar
> - seusite.conosco.me
> - www.nome-do-site.aqui
> - http://site.saindo.do.ar
> - ftp://mirror.siteseu.org
> - https://pediusite.biz
> - www.saiusite.com.br
>
> Adicione nomes para fotos, no arquivo foto.txt. Exemplo:
>
> - 1.png
> - 2.png
> - 3.png
> - 4.png
> - 5.png
> - 6.png
> - 7.png
> - 8.png
>
> Adicione legendas qualquer ao arquivo legenda.txt. Exemplo:
>
> - Agente 01
> - Agente 02
> - Agente 03
> - Agente 04
> - Agente 05
> - Agente 06
> - Agente 07
> - Agente 08
>
> E por fim, dê nomes, adicione dentro do arquivo nome.txt. Exemplo:
>
> - Marina
> - Veraz
> - kiki
> - Nautila
> - Keila
> - Brenda
> - Patrick
> - Nilton

Sei que o real problema está no modo como estou tentado conseguir isso. Veja o código:

**Shell Script**

```html
#!/bin/sh
#
# apagar arquivo, se existir
[ -e saida.html ] && rm -f saida.html

cat link.txt | while read LINK
do 
  cat foto.txt | while read FIGURA
  do 
    cat legenda.txt  | while read LEGENDA
    do      
    cat nome.txt  | while read NOME
    do
        echo -e "<html>\n<body>\n<a href='$LINK'><img src='$LINK/$FIGURA' alt='$LEGENDA' title='$NOME'/></a>\n</body>\n</html>"
      done
    done
  done
done >> saida.html

cat saida.html
```

O problema esta na forma de inserir cada linha, numa nova linha do arquivo final

Este arquivo de saída [o arquivo final -ou- novo arquivo] é gerado com duplacidade por várias vezes até esgotar o final do último laço(`while`).

Alguém sabe uma maneira de corrigir isso? Ou um outro método melhor, de conseguir fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que pude entender, existe uma linha correspondente em cada arquivo de texto, então você pode fazer um `for` de `1` até `n`, onde `n` representa o total de linhas a serem percorridas em cada arquivo, algo do tipo:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# apagar arquivo, se existir
[ -e saida.html ] && rm -f saida.html

total_linhas=$(wc -l link.txt | cut -d' ' -f1)

echo -e "<html>\n<body>" >> saida.html

for linha in $(seq 1 $total_linhas);
do
    link=$(sed "${linha}q;d" link.txt)
    figura=$(sed "${linha}q;d" foto.txt)
    legenda=$(sed "${linha}q;d" legenda.txt)
    nome=$(sed "${linha}q;d" nome.txt)

    echo -e "<a href='$link'><img src='$link/$figura' alt='$legenda' title='$nome'/></a>"
done >> saida.html

echo -e "</body>\n</html>" >> saida.html
```

Outro ponto é quanto as tags `html` e `body`, como só é necessário abrir e fechar uma vez cada, crie antes do `for` e logo após, isso evita que o arquivo gerado fique incorreto.

**Referência**

[Recuperação de linha específica do arquivo (sed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022384/bash-tool-to-get-nth-line-from-a-file)

**Observação**

Utilizar `head` e `tail` (`head -n $linha link.txt | tail -n 1`) ao invés de `sed` também funciona, mas pelo menos nos testes que fiz, foi mais lento.

Comment: Era realmente isso mesmo. Aceite meu Up vote seguido do meu Voto absoluto. Tirou minha dúvidas e sanou meu problema. Obg!